# Split Pandas Dataframe into Multiple Excel Sheets Based on Index Value in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I have this dataset:

[image: Dataset]

That has the column 'Product' with values 'Gas', 'Oil', and 'Water'. I want to write this dataframe to a single excel workbook with three worksheets with the 'Gas', 'Oil', and 'Water' data in those three worksheets.

I have tried:

[image: I have tried variations of:]

and keep getting a type error. Any assistance is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: naturally you'll get an error, you're appending the entire dataframe to each sheet and Product has `NaN` values so you're getting the floating point error.

Comment: can you post next time the data frame directly and not as a picture? That would be helpful. Working on this. You did not defined sheet you want to save the data in in your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC,

you can group by product and assign this as the sheet name, whilst assigning the data into the sheet based on the aggregation.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Report.xlsx')

for group, data in result2.groupby('Product'):
    data.to_excel(writer,group)
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Try to apply this example to your needs:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', index_col = 0)    

Gas = data.loc['Gas']  # look for index Gas
Oil = data.loc['Oil']  # look for index Oil

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Test.xlsx", engine = 'xlsxwriter')
Gas.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Gas')
Oil.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Oil')
writer.save()
```